# ASCII TURNED SHAPE

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, 3d

How can we depict a turned shape simply and nicely using ascii characters in 3D space?

I suggest this method :

Instead of a circle we use a square rotated by 45° for the cutting section so that we only need '/' and '\' characters to draw it.

```
 /\
/  \  
\  /
 \/
```

And we use '_' character for the profiles: upper, lower and median.

```
  _________     
 /\        \      
/  \________\    
\  /        /       
 \/________/
```

Isn't it Turning complete? Well, if you agree, write a full program or a function taking an unsigned integer value N , representing a number of steps , producing a 3d shape as described below.

The profile of this turned shape has the form of a stair step curve raising from 0 to N steps and lowering back to 0 where each step is 2 char('/') high and 5 char long ('_').

Maybe some examples describes it more clearly.

For N = 0 you may output nothing but it's not mandatory to handle it.

```
  N = 1

   _____ 
  /\    \ 
 /  \____\ 
 \  /    / 
  \/____/ 
.
```

```
      N = 2

        _____
       /\    \  
   ___/_ \    \__ 
  /\    \ \    \ \ 
 /  \____\ \____\_\ 
 \  /    / /    / / 
  \/____/ /    /_/ 
      \  /    / 
       \/____/ 
.
```

```
       N = 3
             _____  
            /\    \ 
        ___/_ \    \__ 
       /\    \ \    \ \ 
   ___/_ \    \ \    \ \__ 
  /\    \ \    \ \    \ \ \ 
 /  \____\ \____\ \____\_\_\ 
 \  /    / /    / /    / / / 
  \/____/ /    / /    / /_/ 
      \  /    / /    / / 
       \/____/ /    /_/ 
           \  /    / 
            \/____/
```

Rules :   
  - Margins are not specified. 
    - Standard loopholes are forbidden. 
    - Standard input/output methods.  
    - Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: What if I don't agree ? I may be wrong, but I don't have any task in that case.

Comment: Sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18149/84844

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```
ＮθＦθ«Ｊ⊕×⁷⊕ι⁰≔⊗⊕ιι↙ι↑←×⁵_Ｐ↖²→↗ι×⁴_↖ι←×⁵_↓Ｐ↙²→↘ιＪ⁻×⁹θ⊗ι⊖ι__↗ι←Ｐ←__↖ι←__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBa8IwFMbP9q8IPSWQwdDJWD0NenFYGcOeRbuoD9okpkl3GPvbY9pkWjsc3h7vfe97v/cVh40qxKa0ds6l0UtTbZnCRzKLdkIhV6DvaPRmKrkSeM4LxSrGNfvEK6hYjZ8p6jeBEELRo1sevdY17DlOhdmWbjJQUQSt6F0B1zhJxRdfsJ0O3Uw0DCe57Cn81N@cUhSvY9IpTakhSHLpReOLxQfsD7rnksuuc3Xcez5dPAd2cAdFd6x94swkh4/9Q9WK@lwh7Ay4qQPeC0VHl9lvmF2AKbtK9OwXrx3WrZ89QYs0RPWYf5ZvhRCEP9ZO7ENTngA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＦθ«
```

Input `N` and loop that many times.

```
Ｊ⊕×⁷⊕ι⁰
```

Jump to the (middle) right corner of the front slice.

```
≔⊗⊕ιι
```

Get the size of the slice.

```
↙ι↑←×⁵_Ｐ↖²→↗ι×⁴_↖ι←×⁵_↓Ｐ↙²→↘ι
```

Draw the front slice.

```
Ｊ⁻×⁹θ⊗ι⊖ι
```

Jump to the bottom (that we can see) of the back slice.

```
__↗ι←Ｐ←__↖ι←__
```

Draw the back slice.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES8),  <s>322 282 278</s>  272 bytes

Builds the output line by line.

```javascript
f=(n,y=0,Y=(k=y>2*n)?4*n-y:y,S='___/_25__,/\\    \\25,\\/____/14_/,\\ 14,\\/____/,_____, \\____\\, /    /, \\    \\,_\\, /, \\'.split`,`)=>~Y?(y-2*n?''.padEnd(n*5-(Y>>1)*5-3-y%2-k)+S[y?Y?k*2+y%2:4:5]:'/ 03').replace(/\d/g,n=>S[+n+6].repeat(Y-(n>2||-k)>>1))+`
`+f(n,y+1):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNioMwEMfvfQovSxKTmBq1ByHxtE/gSZoSxY/SKlGqFAJlX91NKCwsncN8/OY/wzD35tms7eO2bNTMXb/vg4CGWHEklYCjsJKHBhVpaKjNLSkF0FozzTOtCVMqcKYUz4hSTPtOnGrmiiBO/xDxXhOn81EpEjA/xjx5z5M39QBE6zLdtprUSMifqoCWugMKAKKl6b5NB02YUVhJGSOXJNR@cToiXJ5tURVjyLEDeZpnlxyw4JgAFD36ZWraHjLVsSsxQpZnbPDp4ht9s8GKQiP56@XW@K0I14caD/4HOEY5AHs7m3We@miar3CATnH4T/gHST5IitD@Cw)

#### How?

For each row \$0 \le y \le 4n\$, we define:

$$k=\cases{
0,&\text{if $y \le 2n$}\\
1,&\text{if $y > 2n$}
}$$
$$Y=\cases{
y,&\text{if $k=0$}\\
4n-y,&\text{if $k=1$}
}$$

Each row is first converted into a main pattern. A main pattern may contain digits: they are placeholders for repeated sub-patterns that are expended afterwards.

The middle row (when \$y=2n\$) is a special case which is processed separately. For all other rows, we compute the main pattern ID \$p\$ with:

$$p=\cases{
5,&\text{if $y=0$}\\
4,&\text{if $y \neq 0, Y=0$}\\
2k+(y \bmod 2),&\text{otherwise}\\
}$$

There are no leading spaces for the middle row. For all other rows, the number \$s\$ of leading spaces is given by:

$$s=5n-5\left\lfloor\frac{Y}{2}\right\rfloor-3-(y\bmod 2)-k$$

There are inner sub-patterns (marked with a digit \$\le2\$) and outer sub-patterns (marked with a digit \$>2\$), which are repeated \$n_1\$ and \$n_2\$ times respectively:

$$n_1=\left\lfloor\frac{Y+k}{2}\right\rfloor\\
n_2=\left\lfloor\frac{Y-1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

The above formulae apply to the middle row as well, but are irrelevant for the first and last rows, which do not have sub-patterns.

Below is what we get for \$n=3\$:

```
  y Y k |  p  |  s  |   before .replace()  | n1 | n2 |      after .replace()
--------+-----+-----+----------------------+----+----+-----------------------------
  0 0 0 |  5  | 12  | ............_____    |  0 | -1 | ............_____          
  1 1 0 |  1  | 11  | .........../\    \25 |  0 |  0 | .........../\    \         
  2 2 0 |  0  |  7  | .......___/_25__     |  1 |  0 | .......___/_ \    \__      
  3 3 0 |  1  |  6  | ....../\    \25      |  1 |  1 | ....../\    \ \    \ \     
  4 4 0 |  0  |  2  | ..___/_25__          |  2 |  1 | ..___/_ \    \ \    \ \__  
  5 5 0 |  1  |  1  | ./\    \25           |  2 |  2 | ./\    \ \    \ \    \ \ \ 
  6 6 0 | n/a | n/a | / 03                 |  3 |  2 | /  \____\ \____\ \____\_\_\
  7 5 1 |  3  |  0  | \ 14                 |  3 |  2 | \  /    / /    / /    / / /
  8 4 1 |  2  |  1  | .\/____/14_/         |  2 |  1 | .\/____/ /    / /    / /_/ 
  9 3 1 |  3  |  5  | .....\ 14            |  2 |  1 | .....\  /    / /    / /    
 10 2 1 |  2  |  6  | ......\/____/14_/    |  1 |  0 | ......\/____/ /    /_/     
 11 1 1 |  3  | 10  | ..........\ 14       |  1 |  0 | ..........\  /    /        
 12 0 1 |  4  | 11  | ...........\/____/   |  0 | -1 | ...........\/____/
```