# Golf Lathe Machine

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, 3d

You probably know what a Turing Machine is but do you know what is a Turning Machine (lathe)?
Ok you already know.. and what about a Golf Turning Machine ??

Ok I tell you..

A Golf Turning Machine is a full program or function taking a list/array (or any convenient method) representing the Profile (P) of a turned piece and producing an ascii turned shape.

An ascii turned shape has square rotated by 45° cutting section instead of a circle so that we only need '/' and '\' characters to draw it. 
And it has '_' characters for the profiles: upper, lower and median.(like the one of this challenge :  [ASCII TURNED SHAPE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194279/ascii-turned-shape?r=SearchResults) ) for simple and nice drawing purpose.

```
      _________
     /\        \
    /  \________\
    \  /        /
     \/________/
```

A Profile P is a container of positive integers values in the range 0 <= value < 26(minimum)
    - Every value represents the radius of a 1 long character section, so the length of the container is the length of the piece obtained.
    - Alphabet are also valid [a to z] or [A to Z] they must correspond to a [0 to 25] value.

- 0 values at the beginning and at the end of the profile input can not be considered.

Test cases:

```
[2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,2] or
"CCCCCEEEEEGGGGGEEEEECCCCC" or
['c','c','c','c','e',.....]
             _____  
            /\    \ 
        ___/_ \    \__ 
       /\    \ \    \ \ 
   ___/_ \    \ \    \ \__ 
  /\    \ \    \ \    \ \ \ 
 /  \____\ \____\ \____\_\_\ 
 \  /    / /    / /    / / / 
  \/____/ /    / /    / /_/ 
      \  /    / /    / / 
       \/____/ /    /_/ 
           \  /    / 
            \/____/
```

.

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,1] or   
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,1,1,0,0,0]
         __
        /\ \   
  _    /  \ \_    
 /\\  /    \_\\       
 \//  \    / //              
       \  / /        
        \/_/
```

.

```
[2,1,1,1,1,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,1,1,1,1,2]           

           __      __
          /\ \    /\ \
         /  \ \__/_ \ \
        /    \ \   \ \ \
       /      \ \   \ \ \
      /        \ \   \ \ \
     /          \ \   \ \ \
    /            \ \   \ \ \
   /  _           \ \   \ \ \
  /  /\\___        \ \   \ \ \
 /  /  \\__\        \_\___\ \_\
 \  \  //__/        / /   / / /   
  \  \//           / /   / / /  
   \              / /   / / /  
    \            / /   / / /  
     \          / /   / / /  
      \        / /   / / /  
       \      / /   / / /  
        \    / /___/ / /  
         \  / /  \  / /  
          \/_/    \/_/
```

Rules :
   - Margins are not specified.
   - Standard loopholes are forbidden.
   - Standard input/output methods.
   - Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Sandbox https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18150/84844

Comment: Can we choose the number of trailing and leading zeroes? (inferring from test case 2) If so, we can require a amount of zeroes that happens to be the output converted from ASCII to unary.

Comment: @someone if you refer to the input nope

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>259 249</s>  246 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers. Returns a matrix of characters.

```javascript
a=>{for(m=[],i=a.length,X=i+25;i--;r[X]>' '|!w?0:r[X]='_',X--)for(y=w=a[i];y>=-w;y--)for(r=m[Y=y+25]=m[Y]||Array(X).fill` `,W=w+(y>0?1-y:y),k=2;k--;)for(x=-W;x<W;x++)r[X+x+k]='/\\  _'[w^a[i+k]|w^a[i+k-1]?(x+W&&2-!(~x+W))^y>0:y&&y-w?2:4];return m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDfboMgGMXv@xTsRiGCU9ctiwzNLvYMdbG0JZ22tv5pqJuSub26w9Z2zQ/Cxzl8nMBOfInjWmaHmpTVR9KnrBcs@E4rCQsWc5wxYedJuam3OGKZ5T3SjBAq44gHJjC7uyZ0/GHHzKWJI0LQ0KlYw0SccaoCRhqqRlmyIn5nSl/Ch4p33auUQsEI2WmW5yuwwjPWWFAFTugS5SuE98yjex146m8ZmdH2RU/LQjrUaq29Dr6fzwFYmnGz0Jla6caCuDyErTUzDI/cwV9dIbTQd/vKMBRpQs@fciqT@lOWoPjpaTwBIPbwhemVpyv/2vUcx0Obi50bHjTD6p5ND7sXnGE833BWLr7HJ3xi67e@ifUWFoAFYF2VxypP7LzawBQWyC7EAcrBkfauykpomuj0f3UiRx2NxrzUFqL9Hw) (with leading and trailing empty lines removed for readability)

### Commented

We are 'drawing' in a matrix \$m[\:]\$, from right to left. The code essentially consists of 4 nested *for* loops, followed by the matrix update.

#### First loop: input values

```javascript
for(                            // initialization:
  m = [],                       //   m[] = output matrix
  i = a.length,                 //   i   = length of input
  X = i + 25;                   //   X   = center x-coordinate
                                // condition:
  i--;                          //   stop when i = 0; decrement i
                                // final expression:
  r[X] > ' ' | !w ? 0           //   unless w = 0 or there's already a character other
                  : r[X] = '_', //   than a space here, append the top '_'
  X--                           //   decrement X
)                               //
```

#### Second loop: rows

```javascript
for(                            // initialization:
  y = w = a[i];                 //   y = w = next width, taken from the input list,
                                //   read in reverse order
                                // condition:
  y >= -w;                      //   stop when y = -w-1
                                // final expression:
  y--                           //   decrement y
)                               //
```

#### Third loop: slices

```javascript
for(                            // initialization:
  r = m[Y = y + 25] =           //   r[] = row to update
      m[Y] || Array(X).fill` `, //   if undefined, initialize it with X leading spaces
  W = w + (y > 0 ? 1 - y : y),  //   W = width of the pattern at this row
  k = 2;                        //   k = counter to draw two consecutive slices
                                // condition:
  k--;                          //   stop when k = 0; decrement k
)                               //
```

#### Fourth loop: columns

```javascript
for(                            // initialization:
  x = -W;                       //   start with x = -W
                                // condition:
  x < W;                        //   stop when x = W
                                // final expression:
  x++                           //   increment x
)                               //
```

#### Matrix update

```javascript
r[X + x + k] =                  // set the character at the current position:
  '/\\  _'[                     //   0 = '/', 1 = '\', 2 or 3 = space, 4 = '_'
    w ^ a[i + k] |              //   if a[i] is different from a[i + k]
    w ^ a[i + k - 1] ?          //   or different from a[i + k - 1]:
      ( x + W &&                //     append a '/' if x = -W
        2 - !(~x + W)           //     append a '\' if x = W - 1, or a space otherwise
      ) ^ y > 0                 //     invert '/' and '\' if we're below the middle row
    :                           //   else:
      y && y - w ? 2 : 4        //     append a '_' if y = 0 or y = w,
  ];                            //     or a space otherwise
```

Comment: Suggest `32` for `' '`

Comment: @ceilingcat This is not C. That would not work in JS.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 68 bytes

```
ＦＬθ«≔⌕α§⮌θιηＦη«Ｊ±⁺ιη⁰Ｇ↘η↗⊕η↖η ↘η←↙η↑↖η→↗η↘§_/⁼/ＫＫ≔⎇⁼ηζ◧_ηηδ↘δ←↙δ»≔ηζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFdS8MwFIav218RcnUKFb3urjqmUJlSxnYtoTlrg13SpWl1yn57TdI6VkXwQEI@nvO@5yRFxXShWD0Me6UJrFGWpoJjFJHPMEjbVpQSHoTkwGKSmkxyfIcN9qhbtFRMRGSnKlqEgc@vfF7w2B2arYJnLJlByOuuBeEwy945NshVfSqVhGSl3uRGlJWx1zFJds20yWSh8YDSILei/maN@5GihI4iWkgzl/DnT6pHSBz@E5skrqhdc81cTK4ILz2HZm6/q/h@J/pyS2Nyf@xY3QJ16xzxFSIbLnF63S1qyfQJJs7292H7zRl3pVgN6ozGwf8w5P9q21Pny696o0V4HoZl6mNlI02X2XDT118) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes a string of uppercase letters as input. Explanation:

```
ＦＬθ«
```

Loop once for each input letter.

```
≔⌕α§⮌θιη
```

Calculate the previous letter's value, since the drawing is done from end to start.

```
Ｆη«
```

Loop that many times; this is slightly golfier than an `if` since it doesn't need an `else`.

```
Ｊ±⁺ιη⁰Ｇ↘η↗⊕η↖η ↘η←↙η↑↖η→↗η
```

Erase and draw the main diamond of the section.

```
↘§_/⁼/ＫＫ
```

Draw the `_` profile at the top if there isn't already a `/` there.

```
≔⎇⁼ηζ◧_ηηδ↘δ←↙δ
```

Draw the right side of the back of the section if this is a new section, otherwise erase the right side of the front diamond we drew last time (the left side was already erased earlier) leaving just two `_`s for the profiles.

```
»≔ηζ
```

Save the size of the section for the next loop.